# How to do a VLOOKUP equivalent (approximate match) for multiple columns in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, vlookup, lookup

I want to perform a vlookup equivalent for a dataframe

Below is an example dataframe for an account and its time on book

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVyxZ.png)

below is the lookup table I want to map the scalar values depending on its time on book

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ughjv.png)

I am trying to do the lookup for each time_on_book column and therefore require 5 new columns [new column titled time_on_book_scalar]. Given the numbers are also in decimals, I would need to perform an approximate match and have tried using merge_asof but unsure how to do it for each column.

Ideally I want to have the lookup similar to the output of VLOOKUP from Excel i.e. the range set to TRUE. If for example the time_on_book is 3.4 then per the lookup table, VLOOKUP would select the corresponding value for 3 in the second dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 different ways of achieving the same results (binary lookup only works if your "scalars" table is sorted on "Time_on_book"):

```
# I didn't want to hard code all the values, so I just used i*10 as the "scalar"
scalars_lut = [(i/2,i*10) for i in range(1,21)]

def get_scalar(x):
    i = 0
    while x>=scalars_lut[i][0]:
        i+=1
    return scalars_lut[i-1][1]

def binary_lookup(x):
    low = 0
    high = len(scalars_lut)
    while high>=low:
        mid = (high+low)//2
        if scalars_lut[mid][0]==x:
            return scalars_lut[mid][1]
        elif scalars_lut[mid][0]>x:
            high=mid-1
        else:
            low=mid+1
    return scalars_lut[low-1][1]
        
print(scalars_lut)
print("#"*100)
print(get_scalar(3.4))
print(get_scalar(3.5))
print(get_scalar(3.6))
print("#"*100)
print(binary_lookup(3.4))
print(binary_lookup(3.5))
print(binary_lookup(3.6))
```

the first function looks cleaner but the binary lookup is faster.